# How might I change CSS values for another media type that already has its own stylesheet, based on a checkbox's status?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I have two separate stylesheets, let's say main.css.sass and print.css.sass.  Currently, the print stylesheet is mostly just hiding unnecessary information and is static.  However, I now have a div I would like to be hidden or shown on print media depending on whether a checkbox is checked or not.

I would imagine this would best be done via Javascript and/or JQuery.  I don't have any problems pulling the status of the checkbox in JQuery or anything like that.  My issue is finding out a good way to have the CSS dependent on that status.

Currently, I am trying in the main.css.sass file:

```
@media print
    #foo
        display: none
```

which compiles to:

```
@media print {
    #foo {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

but this isn't working at the moment.  (This was just a test to see if I could even affect the print.css.sass stylesheet this way, and so far it seems like the answer is no).

As an additional note, the #foo id is not mentioned at all in the print.css.sass stylesheet.

PS: this is using RoR, as well.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that piece of code doesn't work? Does it not get hidden in a print preview?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.  It might actually be that I'm just messing something up syntactically.

Comment: I notice you are using SASS. Shouldn't your file extensions be .scss or .css? Not .sass .. Correct me if I am wrong, but I have never seen it that way.

Comment: They are .sass and work perfectly fine that way, so I guess it is alright to use .sass as a file extension, as far as I know.  Maybe the way Rails handles .css.sass files makes it work out okay.

Answer (score 3):

If you specify the display setting of an element in an included CSS file, you can't easily change it on the element using JavaScript. Instead, you can control it through the addition/removal of a CSS class on the element, using jQuery.

```
@media print
    #foo {
        display:none
        &.visible {
            display:block
        }
    }
```

Using jQuery, you can then use `$('#foo').toggleClass('visible')` based on the state of the checkbox.

Comment: You're right, that's a cleaner way to handle the toggling issue than I was going to off the top of my head, thank you.